# Basic Mono installation wont work

Tags: centos5, mono

Am using a CentOS 5.3 box as prod server and am trying to get mono running there. after much sifting i managed to install version 2.10.2 via yum. i installed also xsp and mod_mono the same way and created a simple hello world web page. thing is its not running. iam guessing something is up with my config files which are responsible for this. Being a newbie on both linux and apache configuration, i dont know whats wrong.

I have tried to follow some relative responses on the site but i cant get it work. So here is what ive done:

installed mono, xsp and mod_mono via yum; added to httpd.conf (mine is in /usr/local/apache/conf)

```
Include "/usr/local/apache/conf.d/*.conf"
```

then i created the following /usr/local/apache/conf.d/mod_mono.conf file :

```
MonoAutoApplication enabled 
LoadModule mono_module /usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_mono.so
AddType application/x-asp-net .aspx
AddType application/x-asp-net .asmx
AddType application/x-asp-net .ashx
AddType application/x-asp-net .asax
AddType application/x-asp-net .ascx
AddType application/x-asp-net .soap
AddType application/x-asp-net .rem
AddType application/x-asp-net .axd
AddType application/x-asp-net .cs
AddType application/x-asp-net .config
AddType application/x-asp-net .Config
AddType application/x-asp-net .dll
DirectoryIndex index.aspx
DirectoryIndex Default.aspx
DirectoryIndex default.aspx
Alias /gpsmapper /usr/local/apache/htdocs/gpsmapper
MonoApplications "/gpsmapper:/usr/local/apache/htdocs/gpsmapper"
MonoServerPath "/opt/novell/mono/lib/mono/4.0/mod-mono-server4.exe"    
<Location /gpsmapper>
    SetHandler mono
</Location>
```

i created an index.aspx under htdocs/gpsmapper but am getting a 503 Service temporarily unavailable.

Is any setting i made wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use fastcgi-mono-server2 or fastcgi-mono-server2. I must warn in Centos 5.x (even 6) won't be easy due to current package support.

I've a successful setup on Ubuntu server running mono 2.10.5 and I know that can also be achieved on Fedora 15.